# Even town problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

Here's the problem.
There are $n$ citizens living in Eventown. They form clubs. In order to limit the number of citizens, they came up with following rules:

1. Each club has to have an *even* (but nonempty) number of members.
2. Every two clubs must have an *odd* number of members in common.

If $m$ is the number of clubs formed, prove that $m\le n$.

I think this is true but I am not quite sure. I'm trying to prove this induction.

I induct on the number of clubs. Let $P(m)$ be the statement:

for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and all $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_m$, if $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_m \in \mathscr{P} (\{ 1,2,\ldots , n \})$ satisfying $|A_i|$ is even for all $i$ and $|A_i \cap A_j |$ is odd for all $i\ne j$ then $m\le n$.

Base case: $m=1$. This is trivially true.

Induction hypothesis. Suppose $P(m)$ is true.

To show that $P(m+1)$ is true. Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_m , A_{m+1}$ be nonempty subsets of $\{ 1,2,\ldots , n \}$.

Let $J=\{ 1, 2, \ldots , n \} \setminus A_{m+1}$. Suppose $|J|=k<n$. Then $x_1< \ldots < x_k$ be members of $J$. Now consider the town with clubs $A_1 , A_2, \ldots , A_m$ with members from $J$ (thinking of them as relabelling). Then $A_1 , A_2, \ldots , A_m$ satisfy the induction hypothesis so $m\le k$. But then $m<n$ so $m+1\le n$ and hence we are done.

Is this proof correct? I hope that I conveyed by my idea properly.

Comment: It doesn't quite make sense to induct on $m$ (while leaving $n$ fixed). It seems hard to go from $m \leq n \Rightarrow m+1 \leq n$. You might try induction on $n$ (though, I'm not quite sure that induction is a valid approach for this question).

Comment: @CalvinLin If you check my statement I am inducting on, $n$ isn't really fixed, is it?

Comment: Depends on how you set it up. From how I read it, your $n$ is fixed. If not, please use $n'$ to avoid letting your notation do double duty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your induction hypothesis step doesn't work.

For $A_i $ restricted to the set $J$, denoted as $A_i|J$, we do not know as yet that

1. $A_i|J$ has non-empty members
2. $A_i|J$ has an even number of members
3. The intersection of every 2 $A_i|J$ is odd.
4. $A_i|J$ are distinct on restriction (In order to conclude that$ \{ A_i | J \}$ has size $m$)

Can you prove these? If not, we can't apply the induction hypothesis.

In fact, these statements need not be true on the restricted set. As an explicit example, for $m = 2$, $n = 4$, if we have $A_1 = \{ 1, 2 \}, A_2 = \{ 2, 3 \}, A_3 = \{1, 3 \}$, then $J = \{2, 4\}$, and $A_1|J = \{2\}, A_2|J = \{2\}$. Several of the conditions are not satisfied.

---

Note:

- Assuming these are true, then what we have is $ m \leq k \leq n-2$. This gives $ m + 2 \leq n$, which indicates that we might run into issues when $ m = n-1$.

Comment: Quite right. I overlooked way too much. Can you suggest me some alternate approaches?

Comment: @AshishK The proofs that I'm aware of require a lot more understanding of linear algebra than what you've demonstrated here. You can do a search for even/odd town, and there are lots of write-ups.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into those.